# In python what is difference between function call and decorators

Tags: python

### Normal Function :

```
def deco(x,y):
        print "********"
        return "sum",x+y

def add(x,y):
        value = deco(x,y)
        print value

add(5,6)
add(5,5)
```

### Decorated Function:

```
def deco(add):
        def wrap(args,kwargs):
                print "*********"
                print args,kwargs
                sum = add(args,kwargs)
                return sum
        return wrap

@deco
def add(x,y):
        print "sum",x+y

add(5,6)
add(5,5)
```

Please anybody can explain me difference. when is actually decorators are useful

Regards,
~

Comment: Think about your first example. Would the same `deco` function be appropriate for using it not in a function `add` which adds two numbers, but instead in a function `sub` which subtracts two numbers?

Answer (score 4):

> <sup>1</sup>When are decorators actually useful?

The purpose of a decorator function is to **dynamically alter the execution behavior of a function**. In your second example, that is what your decorator function does - it alters the behavior of `add` when it is called(Whether or not the decorator is useful is a different story).

The reason decorators are useful is because they allow you to quickly and easily change the behavior of a function, without having to directly modify a function.

For example, say we have two functions. One which calculates the factorial of a number, and one which creates a fibonacci sequence:

```
def factorial(n):
    total = 1
    while n > 1:
        total *= n 
        n -= 1
    return total


def fibonacci_sequence(n):
    a, b = 0, 1
    while b < n:
        yield b
        a, b = b, a+b
```

We deiced we want to modify both functions to print out their execution time. We *could* change both functions to individually calculate their execution time, but this would be verbose and violate the rule of [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself).

Instead, Python allows us to easily change the behavior of a function using decorators. In our case, we can create a simple timing decorator:

```
import time 


def timeit(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        start_time = time.time()
        value = func(*args, **kwargs)
        execution_time = time.time()
        print("Function {} took {}s to execute.".format(
            func.__name__, execution_time - start_time
            ))
        return value
    return wrapper
```

Now, instead of having to copy the timing logic to each function we want to time, we can simply use the decorator syntax on each desired function:

```
@timeit
def factorial(n):
    # body


@timeit        
def fibonacci_sequence(n):
    # body
```

In short, decorators are useful when you have behavior which you want to apply to one or more functions, without having to modify the function directly. It allows for cleaner and more compact code.

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>Note that I changed the grammar of your question to me a bit more readable.</sub>

Comment: Hi Peter, Thanks for reply. For this statement -> Now, instead of having to copy the timing logic to each function we want to time, we can simply use the decorator syntax on each desired function, As we using decorator on each function. Its as good as calling timeit function from factorial or fibonacci function.  I'm still in this confusion. Please help me to understand.  Regards, Ranjeet